# how to display uploaded image in filepond from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-activestorage, filepond

So I've succeeded in setting up my rails backend with react_on_rails, amazon s3 storage and filepond. I'm able to upload an image for a user as an avatar through filepond and I'm able to display it via an image tag in my rails view. 
Now, Im trying to allow user to upload another image to replace their existing image. 
So I have an edit form and the idea is to retrieve the uploaded image if its present. But I'm seeing this error, waiting for size:

[image]

So, here's my edit.html.haml where I pass in the user props. A user has an avatar attached via active storage:

```
%header.mb-3
  %h3.text-center Account
  =react_component("UserForm", props: { user: @user, avatar: url_for(@user.avatar) })
```

I've tried polymorphic_url(@user.avatar), and @user.avatar.download as the props but no luck in that.

In my react component, I'm settign the initial file based on the prop:

```
class UserForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes  = props.classes;  
    this.state = {      
      files: [
        {
          source: props.avatar,
          options: {
            type: "local"
          }
        }
      ],
    ... code ommitted for brevity
```

Heres my component state for file:
[image]

and here's the entire source:

```
"/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBMZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ed1f8477e1258e573f15d0694dd2f1bf48267d28/blob"
```

Any help would be appreciated!